# how to create two matching function in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, blogger, matching

i have tried to implement the two matching jquery function but that didn't works at all

i want that the both function **test1** and **test2** match in this code here

```
//up to so......on
 if(null != a && a.match("test1")) {

// up to so..........on
```

how to match a = test1
match b = test2

**test1** working perfect but how implement **test2** in same line is there any solution available

Comment: provide a detail information. so we can help you.

Comment: if(null != a && a.match("test1") : b && b.match("test2")

i try this but this not working

Comment: you need to debug your code. First, check what happen on a and b using `console.log(a,b)`. And try with `a.match("test1") && b.match("test2")`

Comment: thanks but please guide me to implement (null != a && a.match("test1") this tag and with test2

null != a this is important otherwise script crashed

Comment: If there is compulsory to match a and b then you need to use `a != null && a.match("test1") && b != null && b.match("test2")`. If you want to go into IF if a or b match respectively then you need to use `(a != null && a.match("test1") l || ( b != null && b.match("test2"))`

Comment: brother i  have no words to say thanks

Comment: i works you are genius